# Dynamically modifying the image before upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a project that I am working on that requires me to write some text on an image (watermark) before it is uploaded. Unfortunately, I cannot just overlay the text on top of the image in HTML - the actual image needs to be modified to contain this "watermark".

The process should be as follows:

1. User selects an image to be uploaded (e.g. their avatar)
2. Before the upload, a watermark text gets added to the image
3. The new image is uploaded

I would like to be able to do this completely on the client-side, if possible, using just JavaScript (except for the actual upload obviously). Is this even possible, or must I involve some server-side technology?

Thanks!

Comment: http://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/

Comment: Personally, I would do it server-side in PHP. A) Easier. B) less chance of user interrupting process. Could use CANVAS on client side to make the image before uploading it, this would also allow for cropping etc.